# Jquery function click event not firing in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, jquery

Does anyone know why, in this example, the click event is not being fired only in IE8? Basically, the css style after a click (`.zui-act`) should change the `background-color` of the `label`.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7dFeS/)

```
<div style="width:300px;">
   <input type="radio" name="a" id="a" value="alpha" />
   <label for="a">Alpha</label>
   <input type="radio" name="a" id="b" value="bravo" />
   <label for="b">Bravo</label>
   <input type="radio" name="a" id="c" value="charly" />
   <label for="c">Charly</label>
</div>​

$.radio = function(e) {
    var a = $('input:radio').filter(function(index) { return $(this).attr('name')==e });
    a.hide();
    a.siblings('label').addClass('zui-btn');
    a.click(function(){
        var f = $(this).attr('id');
        $('label').removeClass('zui-act').filter(function(index) {
            return $(this).attr('for')==f
        }).addClass('zui-act');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.radio('a'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only guess is that IE8 won't trigger events on hidden elements.  Makes sense I suppose.  You could adopt the approach taken by jQuery UI buttonset and move the radio buttons off the screen. [Like so](http://jsfiddle.net/7dFeS/1/):

```
.zui-radio {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
}
```

then add this to your `$.radio` method in place of `a.hide()`:

```
a.addClass('zui-radio');
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Change the `click` event to `change` and it should work. You are most likely running in compatibility mode which has a bug in it.</strike>

And why use filter when you can make the selector handle the name?

```
var myName = "a";
var myRadios = $('input[name="' + myName +'"]');
```

Comment: thanks, using name works better but as Ryan mentions, `change` doesn't work and I'm not in compatibility mode

Comment: LOL, I ran it in IE9 and not IE8 when I tested. I thought I changed the mode. :)